# Google Sheets dont return value if both cells blank

Tags: excel

I have this formula in Google Sheets

If both cells are blank, I would like to return a blank cell

```
=if(D2="",B2 &"A" ,D2)
```

How I can do that or the equivalent in Excel?

```
ID      ID1      ID_NEW      
26841            26841A
26842   26842A   26842A

25584            25584A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use follwing formula for this:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(F1);ISBLANK(G1));"blank";"non blank")
```

Obviously, you need to put `""` instead of "blank" :-)
or you might use a reference to `F1` (which would yield following formula: `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(F1);ISBLANK(G1));F1;"non blank")`).

Comment: Hi Dominique, thanks for your answer. I updated column ID_NEW  with what I would like to do as an example

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
=if(countif(C2:D2,"*")=0,"",if(D2<>"",D2,C2&"A"))
```

Hope it helps!